# Find the frequency of words in a dataframe from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
list = ['apple','banana','cherries','dragonfruit','elderberry']
data = {'name': ['Alpha', 'Bravo','Charlie','Delta','Echo'],
             'favorite_fruit':  ['apple banana cherries', 'banana cherries dragonfruit',
                           'cherries dragonfruit','dragonfruit','apple elderberry']}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['name','favorite_fruit'])
```

I want to count the frequency of every fruit in the `list` within the df.
Expected Output:

```
df2
Fruit       | Frequency
Apple       |    2     
Banana      |    2
Cherries    |    3
Dragonfruit |    3
Elderberry  |    1
```

The code `df.favorite_fruit.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()` works for a small DataFrame.
If `df.favorite_fruit` contains thousands of rows of different fruit combinations,
how do I find only the frequency of words in the `list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a loop-hole answer, but you can just filter out the values from the answer you already described.  So if you start with this:

```
>>> df2 = df.favorite_fruit.str.split(expand=True).stack()
>>> df2

0  0          apple
   1         banana
   2       cherries
1  0         banana
   1       cherries
   2    dragonfruit
2  0       cherries
   1    dragonfruit
3  0    dragonfruit
4  0          apple
   1     elderberry
dtype: object
```

You could use `isin` to limit the data to ones in the target list:

```
>>> target = ['apple', 'banana']
>>> df2[df2.isin(target)].value_counts()

banana    2
apple     2
dtype: int64
```

Or even after your original answer:

```
>>> df.favorite_fruit.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().loc[target]

apple     2
banana    2
dtype: int64
```

If the issue is that the `expand` and `stack` operations are costly with that much data, then maybe this won't be satisfactory.  But I think it's possible this can be better than loop based answers?

Comment: Using the first-part of the loophole answer works, but the second part, the code ```df.favorite_fruit.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().loc[target]``` returns a KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, ,see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'. I changed the .loc to .reindex but it doesn't work. The second part of code, if working will be better as it doesn't add more variables..

Comment: @Luc hmmmm this works for me - I copy/paste that line right after your `df = pd.DataFrame....` line from your example and I get no error (also with `target = ['apple', 'banana']` defined).  The Series returned by `value_counts()` should have the fruit values as index, so you should be able to use `loc` with your fruit names to index

Comment: perhaps it's because I've got missing labels in my real data. Nevertheless, if the second solution doesn't work. The first one will do, although I will create many variables then. Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated

Comment: @Luc ahhh this is in your real data - that error should mean that one of your target words is not in the DataFrame / the value counts - could that be possible?  But in that case, `df.favorite_fruit.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().reindex(target)` works for me also.

Comment: @Luc also, note that you can write the first answer without creating `df2`, you just would have to replace `df2` with `df.favorite_fruit.str.sp...` which I think is worse for legibility.  Maybe there is a non boolean-index approach (something like `df.query`), but I'm not sure of one that would work here

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit of a roundabout way of doing it, but if your `favorite_fruit` column is always space delimited something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

list = ['apple','banana','cherries','dragonfruit','elderberry']
data = {'name': ['Alpha', 'Bravo','Charlie','Delta','Echo'],
             'favorite_fruit':  ['apple banana cherries', 'banana cherries dragonfruit',
                           'cherries dragonfruit','dragonfruit','apple elderberry']}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['name','favorite_fruit'])

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
data = {}

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    s = row['favorite_fruit']
    items = s.split(' ')
    for item in items:
        if item in data.keys():
            data[item].append(1)
        else:
            data[item] = [1]

for key, value in data.items():
    data[key] = sum(value)

fruit = []
frequency = []

for key, value in data.items():
    fruit.append(key)
    frequency.append(value)

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': fruit, 'frequency':frequency})
print(new_df)
```

This prints out the following:

```
         fruit  frequency
0        apple          2
1       banana          2
2     cherries          3
3  dragonfruit          3
4   elderberry          1
```

Comment: sorry, it's close, but does not exactly work on my "real" problem. The ```favorite_fruit``` is a string containing a sentence which sometimes contains comma and emojis. The code above gives me the frequency of all the words in the ```favorite_fruit``` column, not just the frequency of words in the ```list```.

Comment: Well then you need to update and edit your minimal working example to reflect that... otherwise we can't help you...

Answer (score -1):

Try using explode function after splitting.

```
df.favorite_fruit.str.split().explode().value_counts()

cherries       3
dragonfruit    3
banana         2
apple          2
elderberry     1
Name: favorite_fruit, dtype: int64
```